Playwright Electron app.context() is not defined - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tracing')
I have an Electron application built with Angular where I have a small e2e test suite using Playwright.
In particular, my test does:
test.beforeAll(async () => {
  app = await electron.launch({ args: [PATH.join(__dirname, '../../main.js'), PATH.join(__dirname, '../../app/package.json')] });
  context = app.context();
  await context.tracing.start({ screenshots: true, snapshots: true });
  firstWindow = await app.firstWindow();
});

This works fine in my CI pipeline running with GitHub actions when running on ubuntu-20.04 and ubuntu-22.04.
However, when I try to upgrade my CI to ubuntu-24.04, I get the following error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tracing')

because for some reasons app.context() is not defined.
Why does this happen and how can I fix this?
